# How to set and clear different bits with a single line of code (C)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, firmware

`data |= (1 << 3)` sets bit (3) without disrupting other bits. `data &= ~(1 << 4)` resets bit (4) without disrupting other bits. How can I accomplish both tasks in a single instruction?

(As this is really only for readability, I plan on `#define`ing this in a cute way like `#define gpioHigh(x) <insert code>`. The alternative is to figure out how to correctly pass a gpio pointer into functions that I write expressly for this purpose, but eff that)

Thanks!

Mike

Comment: Xor is your friend the `^` operator.  That is only true though if you want to flip the bit without knowing what is there.  Otherwise, a set and reset is the way to be sure that you are indeed setting and resetting bits.

Comment: Why would you have a problem passing a GPIO pointer to a function?

Comment: Can't figure out the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible in a single instruction. This is because there are 3 possible operations you need to do on the different bits:

- Set them (bit 3)
- Clear them (bit 4)
- Leave them alone (all the other bits)

How can you select from one of three possibilities with a bitmask made up of binary digits?

Of course, you can do it with one line e.g:

```
data = (data | (1 << 3)) & ~(1 << 4)
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually meant to ask for a one-liner, not a one-instruction...er.

Comment: Is there any difference in code size if we go for single line or multiple line (One for set and one for reset)? I guess single liner avoids reading the variable twice and hence it may save one read instruction.

Comment: @Rajesh that would depend on the compiler. I wouldn't expect it to make a difference however.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

That is, if you want to explicitly ensure `bx` set and `by` clear - if you just want to flip them (regardless of prior value), you can XOR with `operator^` as others have pointed out.

To see why this can't be done in one instruction (of course, you can easily combine two or more instructions into a single LOC), consider the following truth table:

```
B|A|Q
-----
0|0|x
0|1|0
1|0|1
1|1|x
```

where the "don't care" `x`s are irrelevant to discussion. No logical operator has this function - how could it? How can we determine which is `B` and which is `A` if the two inputs are of differing value*? That's at the heart of your problem.

However, consider that cramming this into one instruction perhaps doesn't achieve your stated readability aim anyway. In fact if anything, the two separately is *more* readable - and can still be invoked by some `set3clear4()`.

---

NB - and this is way off on a tangent - that truth table can be implemented by so-called 'Logic Elements' in FPGA architectures, as they're constructed from 'look-up tables' (LUTs) essentially ROM where the inputs `A,B,...` index into the table to find the value `Q`. And of course, `A¬B` corresponds to an address different to `¬AB`.